# Remove the white space before embeded youtube video in wordpress (HTML)?

Tags: html, wordpress, video

I'm trying to remove the white space (gap) before my embedded Youtube video on the 'text' side of my WordPress page.

**Webpage is:** vicash.com.au/sustainability

**HTML:**

`[/vc_column_text][/vc_column][/vc_row][vc_row type="full_width_background" full_screen_row_position="middle" bg_color="#ffffff" scene_position="center" text_color="dark" text_align="left" class="narrow-layout xtra-large-panel-spacing-bottom" overlay_strength="0.3"][vc_column column_padding="no-extra-padding" column_padding_position="all" background_color_opacity="1" background_hover_color_opacity="1" column_shadow="none" width="1/1" tablet_text_alignment="default" phone_text_alignment="default" column_border_width="none" column_border_style="solid"][vc_row_inner column_margin="default" text_align="left"][vc_column_inner column_padding="no-extra-padding" column_padding_position="all" background_color_opacity="1" width="1/4" column_border_width="none" column_border_style="solid"][image_with_animation image_url="282" alignment="center" animation="Fade In" box_shadow="none" max_width="100%"][/vc_column_inner][vc_column_inner column_padding="no-extra-padding" column_padding_position="all" background_color_opacity="1" width="1/4" column_border_width="none" column_border_style="solid"][image_with_animation image_url="283" alignment="center" animation="Fade In" box_shadow="none" max_width="100%"][/vc_column_inner][vc_column_inner column_padding="no-extra-padding" column_padding_position="all" background_color_opacity="1" width="1/4" column_border_width="none" column_border_style="solid"][image_with_animation image_url="7311" alignment="center" animation="Fade In" box_shadow="none" max_width="100%"][/vc_column_inner][vc_column_inner column_padding="no-extra-padding" column_padding_position="all" background_color_opacity="1" width="1/4" column_border_width="none" column_border_style="solid"][image_with_animation image_url="284" alignment="center" animation="Fade In" box_shadow="none" max_width="100%"][/vc_column_inner][/vc_row_inner][/vc_column][/vc_row][vc_row type="full_width_background" full_screen_row_position="middle" bg_color="#ffffff" scene_position="center" text_color="dark" text_align="left" class="narrow-layout xtra-large-panel-spacing-bottom xtra-large-panel-spacing-top" overlay_strength="0.3"][vc_column column_padding="no-extra-padding" column_padding_position="all" background_color_opacity="1" background_hover_color_opacity="1" column_shadow="none" width="1/1" tablet_text_alignment="default" phone_text_alignment="default" column_border_width="none" column_border_style="solid"][vc_column_text]
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/XWcuuhqURT0?list=FLN3Wt2NBx_dlKyf_i8ALtzA" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>`

I've read other questions and people have said add:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

But where do I add this? When I tried it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In the WordPress admin panel go → Appearance → Customize → Additional CSS and you'll be able to insert any CSS code here.

Additionally, switch to HTML mode on any page and then make sure to wrap CSS with `<style>` tags, like this:

```
<style>
/* CSS goes here. */
body {
    margin: 0;
}
</style>
```